# Menubar in datalab keeps vanishing

Tags: google-cloud-datalab

The menu bar in datalab keeps vanishing on me.  I'm using Safari on a mac. Is there a way to pin it to the top of the screen?

Sometimes I can get it to reappear by quickly scrolling up, or clicking where it should be, but it's inconsistent, so I've started just using Shift+Cmd+P to pull up the keyboard shortcuts. Still, it would be nice to use the GUI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been fixed now, should be out in the next Datalab version.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are on Safari, I believe that this is the issue that is being tracked here: https://github.com/googledatalab/datalab/issues/1261

So it's a bug that is not yet fixed.